# How to make a Grid in the Snake Game

Tags: java

When I move my Snake i want it to move in a Grid Style. How can i configurate my width and height to achieve this ?

I tried something like this:

```
public void move() {

if (direction == DOWN) {
    head.y += 1 * Scale;
}
if (direction == UP) {
    head.y -= 1 * Scale;
}
if (direction == RIGHT) {
    head.x += 1 * Scale;
}
if (direction == LEFT) {
    head.x -= 1 * Scale;
}
```

The head is also multiplicated with the Scale:

```
    g.fillRect(head.x * Scale, head.y * Scale,Scale, Scale);
```

I also tried to multiplicate the width and height with the Scale variables without success.

But its still stacking on each other coordinate like in the picture.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AfST.png)

How can i have it that way :

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YspS.png)

Comment: both of your images are the same

Comment: ooops i cant change it

Comment: Plus also create the desired output so we know what you are asking.

Comment: you can just edit the post

Comment: basically i want it to move in the grid

Comment: okey i changed the image

Comment: Can you please post more code? not your whole program(Unless it's very short which i doubt), but just something we can play with. Please make it short(but still complete), make it target your problem, and make it a runnable program. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be multiplying your X and Y coordinates by the scale.

try changing this: `g.fillRect(head.x * Scale, head.y * Scale,Scale, Scale);`

to this: `g.fillRect(head.x, head.y,Scale, Scale);`

Comment: You should not be multiplying your X and Y coordinates **twice**. That is a very important detail. It is already multiplied once, the second multiplication is the unwanted one

Comment: Yeah. you should either store the snake x/y coordinates in the form of where they are in the grid, or where they are on the screen

Comment: Based on what little code you've posted it looks like you're storing them as screen coordinates